# UTC format day(Number) is not showing correct

Tags: momentjs

I convert date into UTC format but day(number) is showing day before

moment('2020-3-27').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm');
result = 2020-03-26T18:30

Answer (score 1):

The usage pattern seems incorrect.

You can try this:

```js
var res = moment.utc("2020-3-27", "YYYY-M-DD").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm");
console.log(res);
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Siddharth Vyas did my solution help?